# Check box is not checked using xpath, it opens link

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please see attached screen shots [image: Agree Term Check box]

using `xpath "//div[@id='divTermsNdConditions']/div/div/div/label"` it clicks on the label and open term and condition link

If use input id `'IsAgreeToNorms'` then element is not visible/reachable.

What will be the solution to click on check box and checked?

Comment: What is the HTML when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: on click on it. it checked. That i want to do with selenium automation

Answer (score 0):

You can try to click it with Explicit Wait,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@data-val-required="Your String Value"]")));
```

You can use any attribute value if its unique,

```
//input[@data-val-required="Your attribute Value"]
//input[@name="Your attribute Value"]
```

You can also use,  `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`

Comment: Visibility condition was failed as you see <input id='IsAgreeToNorms'> show disable. So it won't work